# Trying to build a list in Scheme/Racket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, binary-search-tree

I'm very new to Scheme and can't grasp why this isn't working for me. I'm trying to return an ordered list from a BST structure, but can't seem to get it to cons or append the car to the list. I'm obviously doing something wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
(define (sortList lst)
  (printList '(16 (8 (2 () ()) (10 () ())) (20 (18 () ()) (30 () ()))) (list) )
)

(define (printList lst sorted)

  ; recur smaller
  (unless (null? (cadr lst))
    (cons (printList (cadr lst) sorted) sorted))

  ; debugging...
  (writeln (car lst))

  ; build sorted list
  (cons (car lst) sorted )

  ; recur larger
  (unless (null? (caddr lst))
    (cons (printList (caddr lst) sorted) sorted))

  ; return sorted lst
  sorted
)
```

Comment: Scheme does not have statements, your poor formatting seems to imply that.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? I don't understand your statement.

Comment: `(cons 2 sorted)` makes a new list - it doen't change the existing value stored in `sorted`.

Comment: Ahh, damn, of course! Thank you! - This is part of a much bigger assignment I've been working on for about 12 hours, my mind is starting to fail me... ;D

Answer (score 0):

I whipped up a quick solution:

```
(define (tree->list tree)
  (let recur ((x tree)
              (acc '()))
    (if (null? x)
        acc
        (recur (cadr x)
               (cons (car x)
                     (recur (caddr x) acc))))))
```

Example:

```
> (tree->list '(16 (8 (2 () ()) (10 () ())) (20 (18 () ()) (30 () ()))))
(2 8 10 16 18 20 30)
```

The way this works is that I have an accumulator (`acc`) which starts as an empty list. Then the recursive function (`recur`) checks if the current element is empty: if so, then don't change the accumulator; otherwise, recurse into the right-hand branch, then add the current element to the result, then recurse into the left-hand branch with that.

`cons` builds lists right-to-left, hence the recursion into the right-hand branch before the left-hand branch. (Otherwise, the list will come out reversed.)